# Upload a file to AWS from client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a html with some scripts (client-side).

I am trying to post a json file to a bucket I have in AWS S3 (create or overwrite an existing file).

How do I do this, perhaps through an a ajax or XHR call?

Comment: Have you tried using an AJAX call yet? You may have just answered your question there. Don't forget to give your bucket proper access control parameters. Also: you usually need special programmatic access to edit the contents of an S3 bucket, so it might not be possible in the way you're thinking. Experiment a little bit, then if you're still stuck, please come back and edit your question so we know enough to really help you.

Comment: AWS has a SDK for browsers, read through that a bit: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS provides SDK for browser.

Step should be

1. To configure SDK
2. To upload a your json (in S3 it is known as object) to bucket with validation. i.e. in case file already exists don't upload Else upload it.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html